# Default notification text size

Tags: android, notifications, dimensions, text-size

What is the default notification text size? I use my custom size (simplified):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/app_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_n"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

However this approach (`android:textSize="16sp"`) is not working on all devices, the text is cut on some of them. I just need to find some default `dimens`-ed variable that can be used in my custom notification layout.

Comment: The [default notification text size](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/dimens.xml#L348) is 14sp

Answer (score 1):

You can use auto sizing

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview

Answer (score 0):

you can use this style, into xml:

for title

```
style="@style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title"
```

for body

```
style="@style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification"
```

Comment: Works only on Mobile, not on Tablet.

Comment: This is not working in Android S (API 31). The title looks different in the native notification.